# Best books about notation

Tags: soft-question, notation, book-recommendation

I am reading [A History of Mathematical Notations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486677664) and I would love to read further about the trends and advantages of different notations in mathematics, pure or applied.

Is there any good book or notes on the subject?

Comment: I have also briefly looked for books on mathematical notations. There are some at my university, however I am currently home for the holidays. When it starts next week, I will go and take a look and reply with what I have found.